# How to customise the function behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making an interesting task with the matrix. But now I'm stuck with the code below. I want to make different behavior depending on the enum type.

**My types:**

```
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
using Row = std::vector<int>;

enum class Diagonal {MAIN, ANTI};
```

**First behavior.**

This portion of code runs when  `diagonal == Diagonal::MAIN`:

```
size_t diagonalSum(const Matrix& matrix, Diagonal diagonal) {
  assert(isSquare(matrix));

  size_t sum = 0;
  auto startRow = matrix.cbegin();

  for(auto row = startRow; row != matrix.end(); ++row) {
      for(auto column = row->cbegin(); column != row->end(); ++column) {
          if(std::distance(firstRow, row) == std::distance(row->cbegin(), column)) {
              sum += *column;
          }
      }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

**Second behavior.**

This portion of code runs when `diagonal == Diagonal::ANTI`:

```
size_t diagonalSum(const Matrix& matrix, Diagonal diagonal) {
    assert(isSquare(matrix));

  size_t sum1 = 0;
  auto startRow = matrix.cbegin();

  for(auto row = startRow; row != matrix.cend(); ++row) {
      for(auto column = row->crbegin(); column != row->crend(); ++column) {
          if(std::distance(startRow, row) == std::distance(row->crbegin(), column)) {
              sum1 += *column;
        }
    }
}

  return sum;
}
```

The only **difference** in the code snippets shown above is that they use **different iterators to traverse the columns**.

I thought such a small difference between calculating the sum of the main diagonal and the antidiagonal will help me write neat code, **to customise the behavior of the function** `diagonalSum` **easily**.

After reading about templates, I understood that it cannot help me. So the only way is to overload the function. Am I right?

But how to do it with the one enum? Should I make more types to perform overloading but unfortunately this is not so neat.

Comment: Does it have to be C++11? A C++14 solution won't do?

Comment: Also, try to make it *real* code. What's `firstRow`? Why `row->end()` instead of `row->cend()`?

Comment: Since the only difference is the range of iterators worked with in the inner loop, why not write a (templated if necessary) helper function that contains the inner loop, and that accepts the begin and end iterators?   Then use the enumerated value to select what iterators are passed.

Comment: If your `Diagonal` is compiled time constant, consider using *templates* instead of parameters. If it is runtime, use a switch case inside the function

Comment: C++14 will be okay. Sorry with firstRow. It is a startRow now. There is not big difference between using const and non-const iterators. Maybe I was a bit messy with it.

Comment: About helper function that accepts begin and end iterators. I think usual iterator and a reverse one have different types. So, I don't get this idea right now...

Comment: `Diagonal` is the compile time const. I guess... I suppose every enum is a compile time constant. But I can not understand how it can be used to custom the function behavior... About using switch - maybe there is a good answer.

Comment: what is wrong with a simple `if (diagonal == ANTI) { ...` ?

Comment: btw your title is rather misleading, you actually dont need different types, but you just need to traverse the matrix in a different order

Comment: user463035818, Yes. I think you are right.

Comment: A matrix of signed integers can't have a negative diagonal sum? For this goal, I probably wouldn't have used iterators at all, but something more like a single `for` with `sum += matrix[i][i];` or `sum += matrix[i][n-1-i];`.

Comment: The sum can be negative in my task. What about using indeces. The point is that I think using iterators is safier technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already algorithm to *accumulate*, so you might do something like:

```
size_t diagonalSum(const Matrix& matrix, Diagonal diagonal) {
    assert(isSquare(matrix));

    std::size_t i = 0;
    switch (diagonal) {
        case Diagonal::MAIN:
             return std::accumulate(matrix.cbegin(), matrix.cend(), 0u,
                                    [&](std::size_t acc, const auto& row) {
                                        return acc + row[i++];
                                     });
        case Diagonal::ANTI:
             return std::accumulate(matrix.cbegin(), matrix.cend(), 0u,
                                    [&](std::size_t acc, const auto& row) {
                                        return acc + row[row.size() - i++];
                                     });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you!

Comment: Now I can express what I wanted. I said about the main difference - iterators. I wanted to receive this iterators(usual or reverse) from some function. And this function have a `Diagonal` as a parametr so it can custom a **return type**. But I understood C++ can not do it(except using `variant`).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to genearilze the idea of doing some kind of computation with the matrix.

So there are *functions* that you can easily added. They are *packed in the finction store*. You can unpack them using `enum`.

**Defining functions for packing into the function store.**

```
enum class ComputationMode {MAIN_DIAGONAL_SUM, ANTI_DIAGONAL_SUM};

std::size_t calculateMainDiagonalSum(const Matrix& matrix) {

    auto firstRow = matrix.cbegin();
    auto lastRow = matrix.cend();

    std::size_t sum = 0;

    for(auto row = firstRow; row != lastRow; ++row) {

        auto firstColumn = row->cbegin();
        auto lastColumn = row->cend();

        for(auto column = firstColumn; column != lastColumn; ++column) {
            if(std::distance(firstRow, row) == std::distance(firstColumn, column))        {
                sum += *column;
             }
         }
    }    

    return sum;
}

std::size_t calculateAntiDiagonalSum(const Matrix& matrix) {

    auto firstRow = matrix.cbegin();
    auto lastRow = matrix.cend();

    std::size_t sum = 0;

    for(auto row = firstRow; row != lastRow; ++row) {

         auto firstColumn = row->crbegin();
         auto lastColumn = row->crend();

         for(auto column = firstColumn; column != lastColumn; ++column) {
             if(std::distance(firstRow, row) == std::distance(firstColumn, column))     {
                 sum += *column;
              }
         }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

**Packing into the function store.**

```
static std::map<ComputationMode, std::function<int(const Matrix&)>> functionStore = {
    {ComputationMode::MAIN_DIAGONAL_SUM, &calculateMainDiagonalSum},
    {ComputationMode::ANTI_DIAGONAL_SUM, &calculateAntiDiagonalSum}
};
```

**Base function for using the code above.**

```
size_t computeMatrix(const Matrix& matrix, ComputationMode mode) {

    size_t result = 0;

    if(functionStore.find(mode) != functionStore.end()) {
        result = functionStore[mode](matrix);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Computation error. No proper computation function with this mode" << std::endl;
        assert(false);
    }

    return result;
```

}

**Example of the usage.**

```
auto mainDiagonalSum = computeMatrix(matrix, ComputationMode::MAIN_DIAGONAL_SUM);
auto antiDiagonalSum = computeMatrix(matrix, ComputationMode::ANTI_DIAGONAL_SUM);
```

Full code is [here](https://ideone.com/T1nFB5).